# What affects unzipping speed?

Tags: performance, zip, archive, extract, rar

I do not necessarily have a problem, so this question is just out of curiosity: "What affects the extraction speed of a .rar/.zip/.tar file?"

I know some probable factors, such as RAM, HDD/SDD reading/writing speed, processor speed, etc. But I do not think that's all. I found that archives with a lot of files in them (rather than just a compressed .MP4 file for example) take longer to extract, but I'm not sure "how true" that is. I also imagine the compression rate and extraction time are negatively related (higher compression means longer extraction time and vice versa).

So, any more thoughts?

Comment: why don't you test it? `/usr/bin/time unzip archive_with_lots_of_files.zip` v.s. `/usr/bin/time unzip archvie_with_one_file.zip`

Comment: Writing hundreds or even thousands of small files on any storage media is always much much slower than writing a single large file to same media because of the much larger amount of file system updates necessary for all the small files. That can be best seen on an old floppy drive. Copying just one 1 MB file to the floppy disk needs some seconds. But copying 1000 1 KB files to the floppy disk needs several minutes. A flash media is of course much faster, but writing 1000 1 KB files on a flash media is also much slower than copying just one 1 MB file on same flash media.